# testing parmeters in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I use 4 optional parameters in a bash script:

prefix
state
node
file

I need to check, whenever prefix is used, non of remaining three parameters is used at the same time

Here what I tried in my script without success:

```
$ prefix=1;state=1;node=1;file=1
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && ( -n "${state}" || -n "${node}" || -n "{file}" ) ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$ unset state node file
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && ( -n "${state}" || -n "${node}" || -n "{file}" ) ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && -n "${state}" && -n "${node}" && -n "{file}" ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
$ node=1
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && -n "${state}" && -n "${node}" && -n "{file}" ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
$ file=1
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && -n "${state}" && -n "${node}" && -n "{file}" ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
$ state=1
$ [[ -n "${prefix}" && -n "${state}" && -n "${node}" && -n "{file}" ]] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$
```

Comment: `"{file}"` -> `"${file}"` ??

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is a good resource for validating shellscripts

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question:

```
$  prefix=1;state=1;node=1;file=1
$ [ \( -n "${prefix}" \) -a \( -n "${state}" -o -n "${node}" -o -n "${file}" \) ] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$ unset state
$ [ \( -n "${prefix}" \) -a \( -n "${state}" -o -n "${node}" -o -n "${file}" \) ] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$ unset node
$ [ \( -n "${prefix}" \) -a \( -n "${state}" -o -n "${node}" -o -n "${file}" \) ] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
prefix must not be used with other options
$ unset file
$ [ \( -n "${prefix}" \) -a \( -n "${state}" -o -n "${node}" -o -n "${file}" \) ] && { echo "prefix must not be used with other options"; }
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheap and dirty hack, assuming that you want a variable which is set, but has length zero, treat like an unset variable (you don't say this explicitly in your question, but your codes suggests it):

```
if [[ ${#prefix}${#state}${#node}${#file} == [1-9]*000 ]]
then
  # prefix is set, the other ones are not
fi
```

`${#x}` is zero if `x` is unset or empty, and if `prefix` is set, it has at least length 1. Threfore, the catenated term above will be a number with the last three digits being zero iff `state`, `node` and `file` are empty, and the part of the number to the left of `000` will have at least one non-zero digit, if `prefix` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
```

Demo :

```
$prefix=1;state=1;node=1;file=1
$[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
prefix must not be used with other options
$unset state node file
$[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
Okay
$ node=1
$[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
prefix must not be used with other options
$ file=1
$[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
prefix must not be used with other options
$state=1
$[ ! -z "$prefix" ] && [ -z "${state}" ]  && [ -z "${node}" ]  &&  [ -z "${file}" ] && echo "Okay" ||  echo "prefix must not be used with other options"
prefix must not be used with other options
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
if [ -n "$prefix" ] && [ -n "$state$node$file" ]; then
  echo "prefix must not be used with other options";
fi
```

If `$prefix` is non-empty, then the concatenation of the other three must
*not* be non-empty.